# Get cell index of flex dataGrid

Tags: datagridview

Can you please suggest me that how to get cell index(row & column index) of flex datagrid cell

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://siphu.wordpress.com/2009/08/26/get-selected-cell-value-of-datagrid-in-flex/, hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

create a var of type int to store the column index,

```
public var m_nSelectedColIndex:int = -1;
```

on your grid listen to an event

```
itemClick="id_Map_itemClickHandler(event)"
```

and in that event listnere use statement

```
m_nSelectedColIndex = event.columnIndex;
```

now use this m_nSelectedColIndex where ever you want.
and for row index its very very simple, where-ever the id_map is accessible use,

```
var m_nSelectedRowIndex :int = id_map.selectedIndex;
```